# InnerHTML not working: function not defined

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I'm trying to use innerHTML, but whenever I run it and press F12 on Google Chrome I get this error:

Uncaught ReferenceError: fun is not defined

Here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fun(){
        document.getElementById('checklist').innerHTML =
        "<li> <input type="checkbox" > <label >Checkbox 1</label> </li>";
    }
</script>
    <p><input type="button" onclick="fun()" value="Add"/></p>

</div>
     <h3></h3>
</div>

 <div class="scroll" >
       <ul class="listacheck" id="checklist">

       </ul>
```

I don't really get why it's saying the function is not defined, I would be greatfull if anyone could help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
"<li> <input type="checkbox" > <label >Checkbox 1</label> </li>";
```

is not escaped properly with the embedded quotes around "checkbox". This causes the parser to fail during the definition of `fun`. You can use single quotes

```
"<li> <input type='checkbox' > <label >Checkbox 1</label> </li>";
```

or escape the double quotes:

```
"<li> <input type=\"checkbox\" > <label >Checkbox 1</label> </li>";
```

or use single quotes to define the string:

```
'<li> <input type="checkbox" > <label >Checkbox 1</label> </li>';
```